# Create multiple Named ranges with column Headers in google sheet

Tags: range, google-sheets-api, named-ranges

Need a help from experts. Is there any script available to create named ranges automatically in google sheet:

**Example:**
I have one sheet with many tabs in the same, on the same sheet I have a tab named 'Main data' in the same tab. 
Starting from column B to Column NN I have data's holding in 100's of rows.
The first row of each column holds the name I want to give for each range :

Each range will be each column starting from 2nd row to the last row where data is available in that column ...

See the below-given sample data, consider the first column as column B.

```
I need range b2:b7 to be named as Customer1 
range c2:c3 to be named as Customer2 
range d2:d6 to be named as Customer3 
range e2:e4 to be named as Customer4 
range f2:f7 to be named as Customer5 
....
....
....
....
Till column NN in the same way ..............
```

**Note: Each column will get added with more data in coming days, so the range should be updated if any changes happen to this particular tab of my sheet**

[image: Sample Sheet Screenshot]

Comment: Provide the code that you have tried and did not work

Comment: am good with formulas but not with the scripts so though with forum users if any one have written scripts for the above told purpose

Comment: Here, you can't expect to get ready made code programmed by someone. First of all, you have to try atlreast basic code for what you want and then you can go ahead with questions. That's how stackoveflow works.